# Jasper Reports can't use resourceBundle

Tags: internationalization, jasper-reports, resourcebundle

I want to apply internationalization in my jasper report. Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong?

I have two resource bundles:

```
balance_de.properties

balance_en.properties
```

My resource bundle looks like this:

> mainTitle = title
>
> secondaryTitle = secondary title

I am loading resource bundle:

```
HashMap<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("balance", new Locale("de", "DE"));
parameters.put("REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE", resourceBundle);
```

In **jrxml** report i am trying to obtain the `mainTitle` value from resource bundle:

```
             <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="798" height="20" uuid="0b25b17c-b0f4-4d46-975d-ffea5c518f28"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
                    <![CDATA[$R{mainTitle}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
```

However it is not working, and i have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It seems we are putting the additional information into `Map<Locale, Properties>`. You seem to put the type `ResourceBundle` instead.

I am apologizing in advance, I merely have this example and for us this is working, but I cannot explain exactly how. You can give it a shot, however:

```
    //Load bundle
    ResourceBundle bundle = null;
    try{
        bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(PROPERTY_BASE_NAME, locale);
    } catch (java.util.MissingResourceException e){
        //Not found, not avalable.
        globalProperties.put(locale, null);
        return;
    }

    Properties additionalProperties = new Properties();
    for(String key : bundle.keySet()){
        additionalProperties.put(key, bundle.getString(key));
    }

    //Store properties
    globalProperties.put(locale, additionalProperties);
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this.

```
HashMap<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

parameterMap.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, new Locale("en")); // for English

parameterMap.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, new Locale("de")); // for German
```